# Can't do anything to MySQL table? (Query, Update, etc.)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query into a table in our MySQL database, table is called 'ac_userdata'. Whenever i run a query or update or anything, it just constantly loads and eventually (after ~5 minutes) it times out. I tried dropping the table and making a new one, but i can't even drop it. I checked to see if the table was locked, and even unlocked all tables in the database, no luck. No other table in the database and on the server has this problem, and this is one of the smallest tables in the database...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Erouax

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? This kind of oddity could indicate something as simple as a failing disk...

Comment: @MattGibson Wouldn't that make it affect all the tables in my database though?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one table in database or you have tried to drop the table then why you don't drop the database delete database and create a new one if your current database have no data.

Comment: My database has a LOT of data that i do not wish to lose.

Comment: may be you should try to backup your data and drop database and restore database from backup file